# Dynamic TestCaseSource within dynamic TestFixtureSource

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to run a different set of Test Cases for different Text Fixtures.

Let's say I try to test this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyMethod(int a)
    {
        return a;
    }

    public int MyOtherMethod(int b)
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

It tried something like this:

```
[TestFixtureSource(typeof(FixtureSource), nameof(FixtureSource.Sources))]
public class SampleTest
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(CaseSource), nameof(CaseSource.SourcesEnumerable))]
    public void TestMyMethod(int a)
    {
        var myC = new MyClass();
        Assert.That(myC.MyMethod(a), Is.EqualTo(a));
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(OtherCaseSource), nameof(OtherCaseSource.SourcesEnumerable))]
    public void TestMyOtherMethod(int b)
    {
        var myC = new MyClass();
        Assert.That(myC.MyOtherMethod(b), Is.EqualTo(b));
    }
}

public static class FixtureSource
{
    public static IEnumerable<TestFixtureData> Sources
    {
        get
        {
            CaseSource.Sources = new List<int> { 1 };
            OtherCaseSource.Sources = new List<int> { 1 };
            yield return new TestFixtureData
            {
                TestName = "Only one"
            };

            CaseSource.Sources = new List<int> { 2, 4 };
            OtherCaseSource.Sources = new List<int> { 6 };
            yield return new TestFixtureData
            {
                TestName = "Some even numbers"
            };
        }
    }
}

public static class CaseSource
{
    public static List<int> Sources;
}

public static class OtherCaseSource
{
    public static List<int> Sources;
}
```

I would expect that:

- the first Fixture, "Only one", would test `TestMyMethod(1)` and `TestMyOtherMethod(1)`
- the second Fixture, "Some even numbers", would test `TestMyMethod(2)`, `TestMyMethod(4)` and `TestMyOtherMethod(6)`

That doesn't work: when it runs the tests, the second Fixture sets are run twice, since it's the last values set in my sources when it executes.

So I tried something like that:

```
[TestFixtureSource(typeof(FixtureSource), nameof(FixtureSource.Sources))]
public class SampleTest
{
    public SampleTest(List<int> caseSources, List<int> otherCaseSources)
    {
        _caseSources = caseSources;
        _otherCaseSources = otherCaseSources;
    }

    private readonly List<int> _caseSources;
    private readonly List<int> _otherCaseSources;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        CaseSource.Sources = _caseSources;
        OtherCaseSource.Sources = _otherCaseSources;
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(CaseSource), nameof(CaseSource.Sources))]
    public void TestMyMethod(int a)
    {
        var myC = new MyClass();
        Assert.That(myC.MyMethod(a), Is.EqualTo(a));
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(OtherCaseSource), nameof(OtherCaseSource.Sources))]
    public void TestMyOtherMethod(int b)
    {
        var myC = new MyClass();
        Assert.That(myC.MyOtherMethod(b), Is.EqualTo(b));
    }
}

public static class FixtureSource
{
    public static IEnumerable<TestFixtureData> Sources
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestFixtureData(new List<int> { 1 }, new List<int> { 1 })
            {
                TestName = "Only one"
            };

            yield return new TestFixtureData(new List<int> { 2, 4 }, new List<int> { 6 })
            {
                TestName = "Some even numbers"
            };
        }
    }
}

public static class CaseSource
{
    public static List<int> Sources;
}

public static class OtherCaseSource
{
    public static List<int> Sources;
}
```

And now I'm running nothing, my Sources are never updated (or rather, I'm assuming, too late ; after the tests are built).

Am I doing it the absolute wrong way?
Is it even possible to do?

Thanks for your help!